# When adding google/boringssl to the project in Android, an undefined reference to function error occurs

Tags: android, ssl, android-ndk, boringssl

I'm trying to use [google/boringssl](https://github.com/google/boringssl) through NDK on Android.

I added the code in the are directory.

```
- include/openssl
- include/openssl/pki
- include/openssl/experimental
- ssl/
- crypto/
- third_party/fiat
```

Now we have `add_library(...)` all `.c` files and `.c++` files to `CMakeLists.txt`.

I compiled the project thinking everything was done, but I get an error.

```
openssl/crypto/fipsmodule/sha/sha1.c:421: error: undefined reference to 'sha1_block_data_order_neon'
openssl/crypto/fipsmodule/sha/sha1.c:427: error: undefined reference to 'sha1_block_data_order_nohw'
openssl/crypto/cipher_extra/e_chacha20poly1305.c:173: error: undefined reference to 'chacha20_poly1305_seal'
openssl/crypto/cipher_extra/e_chacha20poly1305.c:256: error: undefined reference to 'chacha20_poly1305_open'
openssl/crypto/fipsmodule/ec/p256-nistz.c:247: undefined reference to `ecp_nistz256_point_add'
...
```

As shown above, there are many functions that are declared but not implemented. Is there a specific way to use `boringssl` in the Android environment??